# Find data with specific date and month only

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find a data with specific where clause of date and month but I am receiving an error can anyone help me with this?

```
select *
from my_data
where date BETWEEN '11-20' AND '12-15'
```

> MS SQL Server Management Studio

I am receving an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion is failing because you are not specifying a year. If you were to specify '11-20-2015' your query would work just insert whatever year you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_data
WHERE date BETWEEN '11-20-2015' AND '12-15-2015'
```

Alternatively if you wanted data from that range of dates for multiple years I would use a while loop to insert information in a # table then read from that table, depending on the amount of data this could be quick or sloooowww here is an example.

```
DECLARE @mindatestart date, @mindateend date, @maxdatestart date

SET @mindatestart = '11-20-2010'
SET @mindateend = '12-15-2010'
SET @maxdatestart = '11-20-2015'

SELECT top 0 *, year = ' '
INTO #mydata
FROM my_data

WHILE @mindatestart < @maxdatestart
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #mydata
        SELECT *, YEAR(@mindatestart) 
        FROM my_data
        where date between @mindatestart and @mindateend

        SET @mindatestart = DATEADD(Year, 1, @mindatestart)
        SET @mindateend = DATEADD(Year, 1, @mindateend)
    END
```

This will loop and insert the data from 2010-2015 for those date ranges and add a extra column on the end so you can call the data and order by year if you want like this

```
    SELECT * FROM #mydata order by YEAR
```

Hopefully some part of this helps!

FROM THE COMMENT BELOW

```
SELECT *
FROM my_data
WHERE DAY(RIGHT(date, 5)) between DAY(11-20) and DAY(12-15)
```

The reason '11-20' doesn't work is because its a character string which is why you have to input it between ' ' What the Month() function does is take whatever you put between the () and convert it to an integer. Which is why you're not getting anything back using the method in the first answer, the '-Year' from the table date field is being added into the numeric value where your value is just being converted from 11-20 you can see by using these queries

```
SELECT MONTH(11-20) --Returns 12
SELECT MONTH(11-20-2015) -- Returns 6
SELECT MONTH(11-20-2014) -- Returns 6
```

Using RIGHT(Date, 5) you only get Month-day, then you date the day value of that so DAY(RIGHT(DATE, 5) and you should get something that in theory should fall within those date ranges despite the year. However I'm not sure how accurate the data will be, and its a lot of work just to not add an additional 8 characters in your original query.

Comment: First of all, Thank You very much. But I would like to use select statement only. Please if you can help me if you can. Also I know that I am not specifying year as I don't want it.`WHERE date BETWEEN '11-20-2015' AND '12-15-2015'` is an example with year that I am able to extract, but why can't without year?

Comment: You're not going to be able to get what you want using what you're inputting  if you just want to put in a month and day and not a year you can use the MONTH() and DAY() but you're not going to get anything back, because the year input changes the value that those functions give back So you'd have to do heavy transformation like

    SELECT *
    FROM my_data
    WHERE MONTH(RIGHT(date, 5)) between MONTH(11-20) and        MONTH(12-15) I'll add this to my original answer

Answer (score 3):

Most databases support functions to extract components of dates.  So, one way of doing what you want is to convert the values to numbers and make a comparison like this:

```
where month(date) * 100 + day(date) between 1120 and 1215
```

The functions for extracting date parts differ by database, so your database might have somewhat different methods for doing this.

Comment: Tried but its not showing any data. I did it with year BETWEEN ('2015-11-20') AND ('2015-12-15') it works but I don't want year to be included.

Comment: This does not work, Example: 
SELECT MONTH(11-20-2015) -- Returns 6
SELECT DAY(11-20-2015) -- Returns 17
 6*100 = 600 + 17 = 617 which would not fall between 1120 and 1215 that is why you're not getting anything.

Comment: @user7107 . . . I'm not sure why this answer wouldn't work.  The year really has nothing to do with the logic here.

Comment: @WBratz . . . month('2015-11-20') returns 11, not 6.

Comment: @GordonLinoff because everything you put inside the () when you use MONTH() or DAY() changes the integer it outputs, Example MONTH('2015-11-20') outputs 11, you're correct. However MONTH(11-20-2015) or MONTH(2015-11-20) outputs 6.

Comment: @WBratz . . . Without the single quotes, those are integer expressions as opposed to dates.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only care about month and day, but not year, you need to use [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to split up the date. Try this:

```
select *
from my_data
WHERE 1=1
AND (DATEPART(m, date) >= 11 AND DATEPART(d,date) >= 20) 
AND (DATEPART(m, date) <= 12 AND DATEPART(d,date) <= 15)
```

Comment: I didn't test this out, but this is a good way to think about this, and completely escaped me thanks for the idea!